# Inserting button in mini cart which is loaded by a javascript code

Tags: magento2, javascript, mini-cart, custom-button

I need to add button in mini cart just below the "Proceed to checkout" button. And the button is loaded using this javascript code:

```
let sourceUrl = "{some_url/index.js}";
let scriptEle = document.createElement("script");
scriptEle.setAttribute("src", sourceUrl);
scriptEle.setAttribute("type", "module");
document.head.append(scriptEle);
const buttonHolder = document.getElementById('button-container');
let breezeButton = document.createElement("breeze-button");
buttonHolder.appendChild(breezeButton);
```

The code in magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html is responsible for the view in mini cart. I just don't know how to add button in this using the code above.